# Meaning of "so that one has someone do something"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can you explain to me the meaning of the bold phrase?

> Zhmud translates *pragmateia* as “science” (2012a, 216) **so that he has Aristoxenus attributing** the invention of the science of number to Pythagoras but, while Aristoxenus does use pragmateia to mean science in some contexts, it more commonly simply means “pursuit”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***To have somebody do something*** most commonly means to cause somebody to do something (e.g., "ask", "force", "pay"). But in this sentence the verb ***had*** means something like "believed", "perceived", "recorded", "claimed", or "stated." (See more here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208233/have-somebody-do-something-vs-have-somebody-doing-something)

Zhmud is translating Aristoxenus, and Aristoxenus has written stuff about Pythagoras. The phrase ***so that he has Aristoxenus attributing*** means that -- according to Zhmud -- Aristoxenus believes that Pythagorus invented the "science of numbers." But the narrator believes Aristoxenus might have meant "pursuit of numbers" instead. And so the narrator is questioning the accuracy of Zhmud's translation.

It's an annoyingly convoluted sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It is an idiom that means "Zhmud is taking the position that Aristoxenus attributes ..."

It is a convoluted and somewhat unclear sentence, and I'd probably try to express what I strongly suspect is the author's intended meaning this way:

"Because Zhmud always translates '*pragmateia*' as 'science,' he reads Aristoxenus as attributing the invention of the science of number to Pythagorus. Aristoxenus, however, more frequently uses '*pragmateia*' to mean 'pursuit.' Consequently, Zhmud's reading is unsound."